# R version 4.2.0 and Swedish letters (ä ö å) not working in newest R release. Anyone found a solution?

Tags: r

I have updated  to the latest R release (R version 4.2.0), but I am now facing the problem that all the Swedish special letters cannot be read anymore. I am working with a database that has many Swedish letters in its factor lables and even if I am reading them in as strings R doesn't recognise them, with the consequence that all summary tables that are based on these factors as groups are not calculated correctly anymore. The code has been working fine under the previous release (but I had issues with knitting Rmarkdown files, therefore the need for updating).
I have set the encoding to iso-5889-4 (which is nothern languages) after UTF-8 has not worked. Is there anything else I could try? Or has anyone come to a solution on how to fix this, other than to rename all lables before reading in the .csv files? (I would really like to avoid this fix, since I am often working with similar data)

I have used read.csv() and it produces cryptic outputs replacing the special letters with for example `<d6>` instead of ö and `<c4>` instead of ä.
I hope that someone has an idea for a fix. Thanks.

edit: I use windows.

> Sys.getlocale("LC_CTYPE")
> [1] "Swedish_Sweden.utf8"

Comment: Thanks for your reply @RuiBarradas: yes it is on windows but it gives: "Swedish_Sweden.utf8"

Comment: Windows is natively Unicode. All strings are Unicode to begin with. There's no `LC_CTYPE` on Windows, that's one of the *Linux* environment variables used to control encoding and codepages. But as I said, Windows is natively Unicode. The closest equivalent is the user's locale, which is used by *non*-Unicode applications. R had issues in the beginning (ie 10 years ago) because it tried to use the user locale for strings instead of Unicode, but that was fixed a *lot* time ago. Some third-party packages may still have issues though

Comment: How are you trying to read the file? Which packages? What codepage does the file use? What is the *actual* output? Post the actual code and actual output. Perhaps this is only a display issue - your terminal or IDE doesn't display UTF8 text properly. Or the file's codepage may not match the code's default encoding. Nowadays, most languages use UTF8 by default but in the past, the user locale was used as the default text encoding.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I managed to get it more or less working with read_excel() for a .xlsx file instead for read.csv() now. I think the problem is really in the latest replease, since the same files and code worked under the previous version and there I didn't have any problems like these.

Comment: What I described isn't an opinion. There's no LC_CTYPE on Windows. D6 [is the byte for Ö](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%96) in all 8859-x codepages. So your code works, but your *console* isn't working properly and displays the bytes instead of the characters. The strings are OK though. To avoid such problems in the future *don't* save files as ASCII, even CSV files. Use UTF8 instead

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem, what worked for me was like the answer above said but I used encoding ISO-8859-1 instead. It works for both reading from file and saving to file for Swedish characters å,ä,ö,Å,Ä,Ä, i.e:

```
read.csv("~/test.csv", fileEncoding = "ISO-8859-1")
```

and

```
write.csv2(x, file="test.csv", row.names = FALSE, na = "", fileEncoding = "ISO-8859-1")
```

It's tedious but it works right now. Another tip is if you use Rstudio is to go to Global options -> Code -> Saving and set your default text encoding to ISO-8859-1 and restart Rstudio. It will save and read your scripts in that encoding as default if I understand correctly. I had the problem when I opened my scripts with Swedish characters, they would display wrong characters. This solution fixed that.

Answer (score 2):

### Use the encoding parameter

I have been able to detect failed loads by attempting to apply `toupper` to strings, which gives me errors such as

```
Error in toupper(dataset$column) : 
invalid multibyte string 999751
```

This is resolved and expected outcomes obtained by using

```
read.csv(..., encoding = 'latin1')
or
data.table::fread(..., encoding = 'Latin-1')
```

I believe this solution should apply to Swedish characters as they are also covered by the Latin-1 encoding.